# Copy sheet to another spreadsheet [Google Apps Script]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I can't get this function working. It's has to copy all the values of spreadsheet "A" to spreadsheet "B".

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "142WNsfQQkSx4BuNhskDM9aXD9ylRHNZh34oO5TBTt1g";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "1h8fDwCUUPHRdmTHu-5gMyqU294ENZxCZcHCNCuN6r_Y";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var y = 1; y < data.length; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x < 35; x++){
      array.push(data[y][x]);
    }
      Logger.log(array);
      sheet2.appendRow(array);
      sheet1.deleteRow(y);
      }
}
```

It now copy's two or three values, but copy them multiple times (random). The function must also delete the copied values from sheetA. But it only deletes the values that are added to sheetB.

EDIT (Updated code)

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "142WNsfQQkSx4BuNhskDM9aXD9ylRHNZh34oO5TBTt1g";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "1h8fDwCUUPHRdmTHu-5gMyqU294ENZxCZcHCNCuN6r_Y";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x < 35; x++){
      array.push(data[y][x]);
    }
      sheet2.appendRow(array);
      sheet1.deleteRow(y+1);
      array = [];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a little, I have found a fix for you (albeit a hack, I guess. Im sure there's a better way of doing it)

Whats happening is, on line 14 where you appendRow(array), you are appending the array *at it's current state* to the second sheet; basically creating a big pyramid of values of your array over time.

If sheet 1 contained something like this:
1,1,1

2,2,2

3,3,3

4,4,4

5,5,5

Your sheet 2 would get this appended:
1,1,1

1,1,1,2,2,2

1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3

... and so on.

You could do something like this:

```
function triggerOnTime() {
  var SpreadSheetKeyA = "142WNsfQQkSx4BuNhskDM9aXD9ylRHNZh34oO5TBTt1g";
  var SpreadSheetKeyB = "1h8fDwCUUPHRdmTHu-5gMyqU294ENZxCZcHCNCuN6r_Y";
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyA).getActiveSheet();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadSheetKeyB).getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var array = [];
  for (var y = 1; y < data.length; y++) {

    for (var x = 0; x < 35; x++){
      array.push(data[y][x]);
    }
      sheet2.appendRow(array);
      sheet1.deleteRow(y);
      array = []; //reset the array contents
      }
}
```

The additional line will just reset the array and add the row you want to copy across.

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't working. It does solve the problem that you've described (the 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 problem). If I have the rows a,b,c,d,e,f and run the function. The function will copy all te values, but duplicates the values some of the times I've run it. And it never deletes b,d and f. I've updated my code in my original post.

Comment: I don't know why you run into duplicates, you must have some code that's not on here that is running. Mine has never run a duplicate.

First of all, outside of both for loops, try something like this:
`sheet1.deleteRows(1, sheet1.getLastRow());`
This will delete all the rows at once, instead of iterating and deleting. It's much faster and gives the same result.

Regarding the duplicates, I would have no idea, but I suggest changing your hard coded numbers of `data.length` and `< 35` to `sheet1.getMaxRows()` and `sheet1.getMaxColumns()` respectively. This is much more robust too.

Comment: Actually in regards to above, the way you have it set up, don't replace `data.length`, it works in this instance.

Comment: Thanks I've solved it. I've used `sheet1.clear();`. Because all the values were already copied. And that solved the duplicate. I don't know why, but I'm getting the feeling that GAS isn't a stable language. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Haha yeah, its kind of the forgotten about project of Google. Im sure they will improve it as it gets more popular, but there are some huge holes in it. It's great fun though! Glad you had success :)